# finding integer element in integer array:recursion issue

Tags: java, recursion

I wrote this recursive method to find an integer in an integer array but it's not working. I tried debugging it but I don't know what the problem could be.

Here's the code

```
public static String inList(int[] primes,int a){
    int index = -9;
    if(primes.length>1){
        index = primes.length/2;
    }else{
        if(primes[0] == a){
            return "True";
        }else{
            return "False";
        }
    }
    if(primes[index] == a){
        return "True";
    }
    if(primes[index] > a){
        inList(Arrays.copyOfRange(primes, 0, index),a);
    }
    if(primes[index]<a){
        inList(Arrays.copyOfRange(primes, index, primes.length),a);
    }
            //shouldn't even get to this point, but eclipse insisted I needed another return
            //statement
    return "Whyyyyy?";
}
```

Comment: What does "it doesn’t work" mean? Wrong result? An error? Also, I think you meant to return the values of the recursive calls. (That’s why Eclipse complains.)

Comment: And why does a function called `inList` return a `String`? Shouldn’t it be either in the list, or not?

Comment: And why are you returning `"True"` instead of `true`?

Comment: Why returning a `String` for a method essentially returning a boolean? Why is the method `static`?

Comment: Why does `index` start out at `-9` when it’s either going to be overwritten or left unused? That just kinda makes things harder to read... and this is binary search, right? Don’t copy the array each time, that’ll probably defeat any performance gain you might have gotten. Just pass the bounds along as additional arguments.

Comment: it return a string instead of a boolean because I return the call to that function in another functions and the output should be a string, either True or False

Comment: the method is static because I won't instantiating an object of this class. It's basically a utility class.

Comment: "it doesn't work" means that I keep getting "whyyyy?" when it shouldn't have event gotten to that point

Comment: index starts out at -9 because sometimes eclipse gives me an error if I don't initialize a variable, even if I initialize it in an if statement and -9 wouldn't confuse me since an index can't be a negative number. When debugging if I printed the value of index and it was -9 then I'll know where the problem lies.

Comment: @evthim: No, I mean, why are you using strings for output and not booleans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have forgot to add return
did you sort your array?

```
if(primes[index] > a){
    return inList(Arrays.copyOfRange(primes, 0, index),a);
}
if(primes[index]<a){
   return inList(Arrays.copyOfRange(primes, index, primes.length),a);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know I had to return the recursive call

Answer (score 2):

Just use `Arrays.binarySearch()`. As you will see from its different prototypes, it will return a negative value if and only if the value you are looking for in the array is not there.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive function to find something in an array would be:

```
public static String inList(int[] primes,int index, int a) {
    /* two breaking conditions for recursion: end of array or number found */
    if(index >= primes.length)
        return "False";

    if(primes[index] == a)
        return "True";

    /* recursion */
    return inList(primes, ++index, a);
}
```

You can call above method with `index = 0` ex. `inList(primes, 0, a)`. This will be much slower than non-recursive find method.

Comment: The point of the original question was to implement binary search, I think.